# [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined. with adminlte

Tags: vuejs2

I tried laravel 5.7 and vue project below sample code with two components. But i had an error.

It gives that error.

[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

Can someone help me to fix this.

master.blade.php

```
<nav class="mt-2">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">
      <li class="nav-item has-treeview menu-open">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link active">
          <i class="nav-icon fa fa-dashboard"></i>
          <p>
            Dashboard
            <i class="right fa fa-angle-left"></i>
          </p>
        </a>
        <ul class="nav nav-treeview"> 
          <li class="nav-item">
            <router-link to="/dashboard" class="nav-link">
              <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
              <p>Dashboard</p>
            </router-link>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <router-link to="/profile" class="nav-link">
              <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
              <p>Profile</p>
            </router-link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

```
<section class="content">
  <div class="container-fluid"> 
    <router-view></router-view>  
  </div> 
</section>
```

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap'); 
window.Vue = require('vue');

import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter) 

let Dashboard = require('./components/Dashboard.vue');
let Profile = require('./components/Profile.vue');

let routes = [
    { path: '/dashboard', component: Dashboard },
    { path: '/profile', component: Profile }
] 

const router = new VueRouter({

    //mode: 'history',
    routes // short for `routes: routes`
})

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router
});
```

Comment: You forgot to specify `id='app'` in your html-code for Vue to be able to mount any components.

Comment: No i already used id='app'. But not mentioned in this code.